# Excel Date value retrieved as DD/MM/YY,how to format it to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: mysql, excel, codeigniter, csv

On converting the date retrieved from the excel sheet the **YEAR** getting inserted as 20XX instead of 19xx.

On clicking on the cell in excel sheet we can know the year and it is shown correctly,but on insertion 19xx is being inserted as 20xx.

When i echo the date retrieved from excel sheet like-

```
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[3]));
    exit();  //output 1970-01-01

   echo $data[3];
    exit();  //output 22/11/66
```

I tried with the following methods-

```
1. $dob=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '.', $data[3])));
```

Output- Some years correct,but some 19xx was shown as 20xx

example- `2066-11-22` instead of `1966-11-22`

```
2. $dob = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $data[3])));
```

Output- YY-MM-DD

```
3. $dob=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', trim($data[3]))));
```

Output- 1970-01-01

Retrieving data from excel in Model-

```
function upload(){
   ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
 /* if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {

  readfile($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    }*/
    if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $firstRow = true;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ",",'"')) !== FALSE)
        {
         $num = count($data);
                if($data[0]!=""){
                    //echo implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $data[3])));exit();
                    if($data[3]!="")
                    {
                        //$dob=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '.', $data[3])));
                        //$dob=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data[3]));
                        //$dob = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $data[3])));
                        //$dob=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
                        $dob=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', trim($data[3]))));
                    }
                     $data1 = array(
                    'member_name' => $data[1],
                     'member_phone' => $data[2],
                     'member_dob' => $dob,
                     'member_outlet' => $data[4]
                   );
                  //echo "<pre/>";print_r($data) ;exit(); 
                       $this->db->insert('member_info', $data1);
                       $member_id = $this->db->insert_id();
                }

        }

//echo "<pre/>";print_r($data) ;exit();
     fclose($handle); 
    }
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',FALSE);             
           }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code is terrible - I would rather try to change the Excel spreadsheet's date formatting - but it works for the example date you gave:

```
$data[3] = '22/11/66'; 
$arr = explode('/', $data[3]);
$dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('19' . $arr[2] . '/' . $arr[1] . '/' . $arr[0]));
echo var_dump($dob);
```

It seems there is a problem with how PHP handles two digit years prior to 1970. Using an example date in dd.mm.yy format from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) I get...

```
$dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("30.6.08"));
echo var_dump($dob); // 2008-06-30

$dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("30.6.66"));
echo var_dump($dob); // 1970-01-01

$dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("30.6.1966"));
echo var_dump($dob); // 1966-06-30
```

I needed to add "19" to the two digit year to get strtotime to understand the year.

Comment: but the thing is some years are in 19xx and some in 20xx,so how?

Comment: Did you mean by creating new excel sheet by changing the date format?

Comment: If your Excel sheet has DD/MM/YY format dates like 31/01/12, I don't see how you will be able to write a function to differentiate 31/01/2012 from 31/01/1912. You could assume two-digit years like 00 to 20 will always mean 2000 to 2020, and years like 21 to 69 are always 1921-1969, or something like that, but it seems like a kludge. If possible, I would change the Excel sheet date format.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem as above,

But **instead of doing processing on php side** what i have done is **changed the excel file's column's datatype as `text` replacing `date`.**

Now all i am doing on php side is as regularly we do:

```
<?php
  $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($excel_date));
 //here you can insert it in your db table if you want.
?>
```

But if you don't have control on excel file which will be uploaded, then go with the above php processing solution.